# iOS-emoji на android

Tags: android, ios, emoji

Хотелось бы в своем EditText'е поместить кнопку, которая работает так же, как в ВК, т.е. показывает на выбор список iOS эмоджи.

Есть какая-нибудь библиотека, которая может предоставить эти эмоджи и элементы, которые могут работать с такими эмоджи, в android?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, почему я не мог найти это раньше, но вот [библиотека](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji).